# Check SSL installed correctly without domain name

Tags: ssl

Is there a way to check if SSL is correctly set up on a server, before pointing the domain at the server (the site has SSL on it's current server, and I want to make sure SSL is ready to go on the new server before I change the A record).

The site, on the new server, will not be in the root directory of the web server, so going to the server's IP address in my browser or using online SSL checker tools won't work (or is there a way to test just with IP address?).

The new server is Apache.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup everything on the new server, then populate both its `/etc/hosts` and yours (or equivalent on your OS) with a mapping between its IP address and the name.

Hence at least the browser on your machine should, based on `/etc/hosts` query the new server, before you do the same change in the DNS for anyone else to see.

HTTPS and direct browsing by IP addresses does not mix well because:

- certificates are based on hostnames, not IP addresses
- with SNI, the client needs to pass an hostname at the TLS level for the server to properly select the certificate, in case of multihosting on a single IP address

Comment: Making use of my local machine's hosts file was actually my first thought, but I read somewhere that it wouldn't work for SSL, even if the server has SSL installed correctly. I can confirm simply editing my hosts file as normal did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's enough to test SSL/TLS, not HTTP level including things like redirects and linked resources (CSS, JS, images, etc)

```
 openssl s_client -connect address:port -servername hostname_for_SNI </dev/null
 # or <NUL: on Windows
 # optionally add -quiet to suppress most non-error output
```